Compiling 2.x Linux Kernel Drivers into Linux 6.x version drivers
I was doing some Red Hat v2.5 work under Ubuntu Server v6.11 when suddenly, and without warning, I spied:
    // create class device attributes
    ret = add_classdev_attrs(foo->poo->class_device.class, foo_poo_class_attrs);
    if (ret) {
        LOG_ERR("failed to add FOO poo class device attributes\n");
    }
    class_set_devdata(foo->poo->class_device.class, foo);

which after adding class device attributes .show() .store() for a device:
    class_set_devdata(foo->poo->class_device.class, foo);

did not compile as it has been deprecated.
I found I have compiled libraries and compiled apps for a device that no longer has any support, is ex-military equipment and had unobtainium drivers such that even getting their source was impossible. I cannot recompile them, so it must work as it did previously.
The libraries and tools are looking for files in exactly the same place they were in 2004.
This creates, indirectly, some memory apertures as files under:
/sys/class/foo/device0bar
/sys/class/foo/device0baz
/sys/class/foo/device0qux

and nothing else will suffice.
What is the equivalent of:
class_set_devdata(foo->poo->class_device.class, foo);

or is it unnecessary in the scheme of things?
